# AmplifyConfig folder is not generated in xCode project navigation

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Following the getting started tutorial on the amplify [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/generate-model/q/integration/ios)

> In Xcode, make sure the project navigator is displayed. You can use
> Cmd+1 to switch to this view. Open the schema file located at Todo >
> AmplifyConfig > schema.graphql. In your project folder, this file is
> located at "amplify/backend/api/amplifyDatasource/schema.graphql".

The amplifyConfig file is not generated and cannot be found in the project navigator. I was hoping someone can help explain how I may get this folder generated as mentioned in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
amplify add api
```

will create this schema file for you. And

```
amplify codegen models
```

will generate the corresponding swift model files.